# Recommendations for fitting a classifier on panel data to predict one step head forecasted class

Tags: time-series, classification

I am predicting the binary class, i.e. if it's in top10 or not, of a security based upon it's performance using predictors from current time. So it's simply a cross sectional classifier. As of now I've used random forest and neural net for this purpose.

Now I want to extend it so that I can one step ahead prediction of the class. Please suggest some starting point. I understand it might be open ended question. Thanks for reading.

I know how to use time series, but I'm not sure how to go so for a classifier. Also all the predictors are numeric variables, none of them are categorical.

I'm doing all in R, so it would be great if I get related pointers, not a strict constraint though.

Comment: You want to add lags of explanatory variables to your model?

Comment: If it works, sure why not. Thing is does ARMA work with Classifier? Initially I thought simply shifting the Class one step ahead. Not sure how it would play out.